# How to get ngModel of input in the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Consider I have controller and input with `ngModel` .

I want to get this ngModel in the controller and execute `$setViewValue` on it .

The snippet is attach .  The trying to execute  - `$setViewValue` gives error -

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '$setViewValue' of undefined
```

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []); 
     myAppModule.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
        $scope.entityMail.$setViewValue("blabla@aaa.com");
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <form ng-controller="myCtrl">
         Mail <input type="text" ng-model="entityMail">
     </form>
 </div>
```

How to get this ngModel correctly and execute `$setViewValue` on it ?

**Edit:**

I edited my code . I must use it with `$setViewValue`.

Comment: Why are you setting a 3 second interval ? `entityMail` is undefined because it doesn't have any value yet.

Comment: See my update please  . How to change it even if there is no value yet ?

Comment: Why *must* you use `$setViewValue` ? Just setting the values, `$scope.entityMail = 'something'` will be reflected in the view

Comment: why not just use  $scope.entityMail = "blabla@aaa.com"; ?

Comment: @Tom : I just wanted to simplify my code , in the real code I have ngModel to directive and I must use setViewValue .

Comment: you really can't view it down in the dom tree. you only can get it up in the tree

Answer (score 2):

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []); 
    myAppModule.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope,$interval) {
            $scope.entityMail  = "blabla@aaa.com";
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to declared $scope.entityMail as a object, then only you can apply $setViewValue in this.

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []); 
        myAppModule.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
                    $scope.entityMail = {};
                    $scope.entityMail.$setViewValue("blabla@aaa.com");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $setViewValue you can directly assign the value to the ngModel

```
$scope.entityMail  = "blabla@aaa.com";
```